# GPIO : issue with sym link

Tags: linux, gpio

I used to create a symbolic link on `/dev/gpiochipN` with kernel 4.09 and libgpiod 1.0.1 and used `gpioinfo <my_symbolic_link>` to have access to GPIO information.

Now I am with kernel 4.19 and libgpiod 1.3. With command `gpioinfo /dev/gpiochipN`, all is working fine. However, if I create a symbolic link on this device, and use command `gpioinfo <my_symbolic_link>`, I receive this message: `Inappropriate ioctl for device`.

Has something changed in libgpiod?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you provide the actual symlink?

Comment: In /dev : myGPIO -> gpiochip1

Comment: Symlink is created by UDEV rule, but it does not change anything if i create it manually

Comment: So you have `/dev/myGPIO` pointing to `/dev/gpiochip1`?

Comment: yes. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, after the commit [d9b1c1f14c6](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/commit/?id=d9b1c1f14c6bebab3c931086bbbdd31c2a8a3f67) libgpiod doesn't allow symlinks to be supplied as device nodes. This looks like a regression in the tool. For time being the [fix](https://marc.info/?l=linux-gpio&m=158101285414590) has been submitted.

**UPDATE** [Fix](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/commit/?id=ba91f719044f4350595b8b0f19b483da38540e02) (with slight modifications by maintainer) has been applied. Thus, libgpiod v1.5.x and v1.4.x have the fix included in the corresponding (v1.5.1 and v1.4.3) stable release.